# accumulation point, Lang text

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I'm reading the complex analysis text by Lang, there is something that kinda confuse me. 
He defines the accumulation point in two separate way, one for sequence and one for infinite set, (i think they are the same thing)
for the sequence, he define that a point of accumulation of sequence ${{z_n}}$ is the point v such that given $\epsilon$ there exist infinite many integers n such that
$$ | z_n - v| < \epsilon $$

and for infinite set S, it is a complex number v such that given an open set U 
containing v, there exist infinitely many elements of S lying in U.

I want to show that if every infinite subset of S has a point of accumulation in S, then every sequence of elements of S has a point of accumulation in S.

so can I take the sequence to be an infinite subset of S, then by the hypothesis, the result follows??
the wording kinda confuse me a bit since English is not my first language. 
thank you in advance.

Comment: A sequence gives rise to a countable set while an infinite set could be uncountable. This is probably the difference that has been thought of. For countable sets, the definitions are equivalent.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. Since every sequence of elements of S is an infinite subset of S the result follows.

Comment: @John Douma ,  thank you for your answer, I got it now!!

Comment: @Khoata Remember to consider the case where the sequence only takes a finite number of distinct values, e.g. a constant sequence. But in that case it will be clear that there will have to be an infinite number of $n$ such that $|z_n - v|\lt \epsilon$ where $v$ is one of the values the sequence takes an infinite number of times.

Comment: @John Douma thank you again, yeah, for that case then it's straightforward,

Comment: @JohnDouma Not every sequence in $S$ contains infinitely many elements of $S.$

Comment: @zhw.Look two comments above yours.

Comment: Sequences and sets **should** behave differently (regarding accumulation points). The sequence $(-1)^n$ has two accumulation points: $1$ and $-1$, but the corresponding set, $\{ -1, 1 \}$ has no accumulation point.